# Given 2 coordinates and an angle, find C coordinate

Tags: math, racket, formula, algebra, calculus

The following is an equilateral triangle:
Bisecting ∠ACB splits the triangle into two congruent triangles (and the bisector meets the line AB at its midpoint and forms a right angle!)

if  A is (1,0) and B is (5,0) and C is (c,y) and D is (c,0).
C has an angle of tan(theta/2). In this case 60 degrees. How would I derive a formula in order to get the following output 3.4641016151377553.

Another example:
A (-2,0), B(6,0), theta is: 120 degrees
The output is: 2.309401076758504

**Output must be in radians (pi/180)**

**Output is the C coordinate**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIQ4u.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is intended to help people with computer programming problems.  If your question is primarily math related (which it appears to be), you are likely to get better results posting it to https://math.stackexchange.com/.  If you are having trouble coding this up, please post the code you have written so far and describe how its behavior differs from your expectations.

Comment: Racket code: (sqrt (-  (expt (- b a) 2) (expt (/ (+ a b) 3) 2))))-- this only works for the first example and doesnt incorporate the theta angle

Comment: So D is the midpoint of A and B? Will A and B always be on the X axis?

Comment: a posted a picture above

Comment: Still need help

Comment: If the answer given below helped, you really should mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the Points `A=(a,0)` and `B=(b,0)` are on the x-axis and that `ABC` is an isosceles triangle with the angle `theta` at `C`:
[image]
Then `D` has the coordinates `((a+b)/2,0)`. And in the right angled triangle `ADC` we have `tan(theta/2) = (b-a)/2 / h`. Hence we get the y-coordinate of C as `h = (b-a)/2/tan(theta/2)`.

Here is the corresponding racket code:

```
#lang racket
(require math)
(define (half v) (/ v 2))
(define (deg2rad angle_deg) (* angle_deg (/ pi 180)))
(define (cy a b theta) (/ (half (- b a)) (tan (deg2rad (half theta)))))
(cy 1 5 60)
(cy -2 6 120)
```

giving the output:

```
3.464101615137755
2.309401076758504
```

Comment: so to find the y value of the c coordinate i would compute this formula (b-a)/2/tan(theta/2)? The output I get is #i-0.3122399043233184

Comment: yes. Note that most implementations of the function `tan` expect its argument to be in radians, not degrees. So `theta` must probably entered in radians into this formula. (`angle_rad = angle_deg/180 * pi`)

Comment: So how would i implement this into the formula. Would it be (b-a)/2/(* (/ (tan(theta/2)) 180) pi)

Comment: I computed A (1, 0) B (5, 0) and theta as 60, but i'm still getting a value of #i-17.89002871329477 after converting degrees to radians

Comment: `(/ (/ (- 5 1) 2) (tan (* (/ 60 2) (/ pi 180))))` gives `3.464101615137755`